# integrating Ux.locale.Manager extension into MVC application using Castle MonoRail

Tags: extjs, localization, internationalization, castle-monorail

I am trying to integrate the Ux.locale.Manager (https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.locale.Manager) extension into our MVC application which uses Castle MonoRail.

I am experiencing difficulties in trying to get the extension to work.

Is this because Ext JS/Sencha MVC is incompatible with MonoRail MVC? I need to know this for if that is the case then I will need to find another method to localize/internationalize our application (which uses Ext JS for forms, grids, etc.).

Thanks in advance for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to integrate the extension succesfully into my (Castle Monorail) MVC application. One needs to make the tpl value in ajaxConfig refer to a method in a controller that returns the json locale values instead of making it refer to the json locale files. I did not have to alter any code in the Manager.js file.